# Can I change string data in dataframe in to datetime in specific format?

Tags: python, dataframe, datetime

I want to change string datas in dataframe to datetime data
but it's not working
for example I have dataframe data here

```
TotTime
D1 12:24:13.88
D1 12:24:14.88
D1 12:24:15.88
D1 12:24:16.88
D1 12:24:17.88
```

and I want to change this data in date time to caculate
How can I?

I tried like below

```
df.StepTime = pd.to_datetime(df.StepTime)

dfn['totTime'] = dfn.totTime.apply(lambda totTime: datetime.strptime(totTime, 'D%d %H:%M:%S'))

dfn['totTime'] = dfn.totTime.apply(lambda totTime: parse(totTime))
```

but it was not working

Comment: Is "D1" part of the text? You might need to split on the space to only get the time information

Comment: yes it's part of the text, it means day 1 and I arleady got data from others with this format,,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, that you probably don't need datetime type, but timedelta type instead.

datetime type is for exact point of date and time.

timedelta is for time periods with different length.

I made my gess based on name 'TotTime' in your code.

You can create timedelta type from your string with some code like this:

```
def get_days(_str):
  return int(_str[1:]) # assume first simbol is 'D' and others is number of days

def get_mss(_str): #assume format is 15.88
  s_ms = _str.split('.')
  s = int(s_ms[0])
  ms = int(s_ms[1]) * 10 # 0.88 is 880 milliseconds, not 88
  return s, ms

def get_seconds(_str): # assume format is 12:24:15.88
  hms = _str.split(':')
  h = int(hms[0])
  m = int(hms[1])
  s, ms = get_mss(hms[2])
  return h, m, s, ms

def str_to_td(_str):
  dt1 = _str.split(' ')
  days = get_days(dt1[0])
  h, m, s, ms = get_seconds(dt1[1])
  return datetime.timedelta(days = days, hours = h, minutes = m, seconds = seconds, milliseconds = ms)
```

Comment: How can I cange string to time delta?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.astype()` with the datetime64 data type.

```
df['totTime'] = df['totTime'].astype('datetime64[ns]')
```

Comment: There is an error like 'Unknown string format:', 'D0 00:21:00.62'